# Can't build solution due to Android SDK missing even though it's a C# winforms application?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, build

I can't seem to build my C# winforms application due to the following error:

```
Xamarin.Android for Visual Studio requires Android SDK. Please install it or set Android SDK path on Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android Settings menu.
```

This is an existing project (months old) which I have build many times never seeing this error.  I recently got a new work computer and downloaded the solution from our SVN and got this error.  I searched through all the references and there is nothing linking it to Xamarin or Android so I have no idea why this error is occurring.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio is installed on this new computer? and what was installed on the one where it compiles properly?

Comment: Both computers have VS 2015 update 3

Comment: Did you tried cleaning the solution then rebuilding? search the entire solution for words "android" and "xamarin"

Comment: Clean didn't seem to help, no results found for both of those search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin/VS will still look for SDKs because it's a global setting. You will have to download it. Thank Microsoft.